# Difficulty using both greek letter and subscript in label

Tags: label, subscript, delta

I am trying to create a y label that has both the Delta symbol and a subscript in it but am having problems combining the two.  This is what I have for the label in my ggplot expression:

```
y=expression("expression(Delta)"~CO[2]~'(mg C/kgSW)'))
```

The subscript is working, but the delta symbol is not coming up correctly.

Thank you!